# Can it be possible to use where clause in order by condition oracle?

Tags: oracle

Actually I have a birthday table and daily wise I am showing list of birthdays to all of our offices. But I want to show the birthdays of the employees first to their office employees and then others. My query is below:-

```
select * 
from TBL_VIEW_EMPL_MST 
where ltrim(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(BIRTHDATE,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd-mm'),'0') = 
      ltrim(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'dd-mm'),'0') 
order by office_code DESC;
```

Comment: Sample data would really help your question here.

Comment: very simplified processing order in sql is: retrieve-data / joins, process where-condition, order final resultset. no where in order possible. why not just "order by BIRTHDATE asc, office_code desc" or "order by office_code desc, BIRTHDATE asc"?

Answer (score 2):

I *think* I understand what you are asking.

Depending on *who* executes the query, you'd want to display employees who work in his/her department first, and then other departments. If that's so, an example based on Scott's sample schema.

`EMP` table contents:

```
SQL> select deptno, ename, job from emp order by deptno, ename;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        10 CLARK      MANAGER
        10 KING       PRESIDENT
        10 MILLER     CLERK
        20 ADAMS      CLERK
        20 FORD       ANALYST
        20 JONES      MANAGER
        20 SCOTT      ANALYST
        20 SMITH      CLERK
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN
        30 BLAKE      MANAGER
        30 JAMES      CLERK
        30 MARTIN     SALESMAN
        30 TURNER     SALESMAN
        30 WARD       SALESMAN

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

A query you might be looking for:

- I'm using a parameter to enter employee's name; you might be using `USER` or something else (a function, perhaps? Can't tell)
- the `MY_DEPT` CTE returns `par_my_name` employee's department number
- note the `ORDER BY` clause which utilizes `my_dept`'s result

For `SCOTT`, who works in `DEPTNO = 20`, this department will be sorted first:

```
SQL> with my_dept as
  2    (select deptno
  3     from emp
  4     where ename = '&par_my_name'
  5    )
  6  select e.deptno, e.ename, e.job
  7  from emp e cross join my_dept m
  8  order by case when e.deptno = m.deptno then 1
  9                else 2
 10           end,
 11           e.deptno;
Enter value for par_my_name: SCOTT

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        20 SMITH      CLERK
        20 FORD       ANALYST
        20 ADAMS      CLERK
        20 JONES      MANAGER
        20 SCOTT      ANALYST
        10 CLARK      MANAGER
        10 KING       PRESIDENT
        10 MILLER     CLERK
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN
        30 TURNER     SALESMAN
        30 WARD       SALESMAN
        30 MARTIN     SALESMAN
        30 JAMES      CLERK
        30 BLAKE      MANAGER

14 rows selected.
```

For `MARTIN`, department `30` goes first:

```
SQL> /
Enter value for par_my_name: MARTIN

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        30 JAMES      CLERK
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN
        30 WARD       SALESMAN
        30 TURNER     SALESMAN
        30 MARTIN     SALESMAN
        30 BLAKE      MANAGER
        10 MILLER     CLERK
        10 CLARK      MANAGER
        10 KING       PRESIDENT
        20 JONES      MANAGER
        20 ADAMS      CLERK
        20 SMITH      CLERK
        20 FORD       ANALYST
        20 SCOTT      ANALYST

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```